# Technical term for smooth scrolling digital volume encoder

Tags: audio, potentiometer

I am making a bluetooth volume control from a machined aluminium billet.

I cannot find a technical name for the digital volume encoder that would provide that smooth rotation.

Or am I approaching this wrong and should be looking at smooth analog pots and then convert the signal to digital?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a "detentless rotary encoder". They often come with quadrature output, so you may need to decode it in order to provide discrete up/down steps.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear to me what you're *really* asking, but I'll try anyway.

A digital volume controller would be a [rotary encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_encoder). They are available in either absolute or relative versions.[image]